# Selectmenu widget appearing behind listview

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

When I push my selectmenu widget, the dropwdown is appearing behind my listview which is placed below the select.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed" role="banner"> 
        <h1>Testapp</h1>
    </div><!-- /header --> 
    <div id="main-container" data-role="content"> 
        <select name="number-selector" id="number-selector">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
     <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" id="list1"> 
        <li>
          <p> Bla </p>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <p> Bla </p>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <p> Bla </p>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <p> Bla </p>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <p> Bla </p>
        </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#list1{
    position:relative;
    width:280px;
    padding:0;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
#main-container {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    top:45px; bottom:48px; left:0;
    height:100%;

}
```

I have no css for the selectmenu yet.

I want the dropdown to appear in front of the listview which is below the selectmenu. However, at this point, I can't see it because it seems like it appears behind it. I guess there is something with the CSS properties for the other IDs, but I am not able to see what.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Add `margin-top` to `.ui-listview` http://jsfiddle.net/RewmB/